# How to load image on page load in Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using `canvas` for drawing but issue is this on page load I want to show an image on `canvas` so the user can continue from where he left

```
<div id="wPaint" style="position:relative; width:100%; height:600px; background-color:white; border:1px solid black;  resize: both; ">
</div>
```

`canvas` is loaded in this div. if I inspect then `canvas` code is below image

[image: canvas code image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduction

The question is referring to a scenario when you have a `canvas` and the user can change its content. I assume that this works and you need to be able to save the content of the `canvas` as an image and load that saved image and draw into the `canvas` the given image.

## Exporting the content

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas"); //you can change this to your image
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

## Saving the image

Once you have successfully created the `img` variable, you can save it. You can store it into `localStorage`, like

```
localStorage.setItem('saved', img)
```

You can store it differently as well, like sending the image to your server in a POST request, but, for the purpose of this question I aim to have a simple solution that works. It would be another task to store this as a file or something of the like in your server.

## Loading the image

```
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = localStorage.getItem('saved');
```

It is possible that `img` was not saved yet, like in the first load. You will need to properly handle that case, like

```
if (img.src) {
    //do some stuff
}
```

## Putting an image into a canvas

```
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, dx, dy);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i tried your code it gives this mind:636 Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function
    at mind:636:8,     here it is my code       var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("wPaint-canvas");
let img = "/test/uploads/wPaint-62550e4f05ab7.png";
canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.drawImage(img, dx, dy);

Comment: @UmerFayyaz your code treats `getElementsByClassName` as if it would return a single element. But, in reality, it returns an array-like-object. Try with `var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("wPaint-canvas")[0];/*...*/`

Comment: yes that error solved now on this line canvas.drawImage(img, 0, 0);  canvas.drawImage is not a function
    at mind:637:8

Comment: @UmerFayyaz I had a typo in my answer (fixed). You need to call `drawImage` of the context of the `canvas`, not the `canvas` itself: `canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, dx, dy);`

Comment: Thanks for help i think this is the last error.     Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.

Comment: on this line canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);

Comment: @UmerFayyaz you are right, I had an error in my answer. You need to instantiate an `img` and set its `src` to the value you get from the storage. Edited my answer.

Comment: @UmerFayyaz I'm happy to help. The tip I can give you is to never back down from a challenge. Try to solve things on your own (and consult the documentation and other developers when it is too difficult) and with time you will accumulate experience and you will have an increasingly easy time while you solve problems. You are definitely on the right track.

Comment: apologize for disturb you.... facing one issue can you see below answer of me actually this is an issue where i stuck on Thanks

Comment: @UmerFayyaz this seems to be a rotation issue. Basically you have a direction, specified by the main line of your vector and you need to display a triangle which has 3 smaller lines. Line1: It is perpendicular to your main line. Line2 & Line3: They are displayed between Line1 and the end of the main line. This can be nicely represented using trigonometrical formulas. I would like to help you, but I need the following in order to do so: I need you to create another question, paste the answer you have written here into the new question and create a snippet there where this is reproduced.

Comment: @UmerFayyaz I need you to share the link of your new question here when you are finished writing it, so I will know that it exists. Playing around with a snippet that reproduces the problem will help me in helping you. Once you are finished with creating the other question and sharing its link, it is advisable to remove your answer here, because it is essentially another question.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I create arrow but issue is arrow not perfect on all direction... top , down , right and left direction arrow not perfect

here it image
[image]

here it is my code

```
_drawLineMove: function (a) {
            this._drawShapeMove(a, 1);
            
            var b = this.canvasTempLeftOriginal,
                c = this.canvasTempTopOriginal;
            //var headlen = 10; // length of head in pixels  

                a.pageX < b && ((a.x = a.x + a.w), (a.w = -1 * a.w)),
                a.pageY < c && ((a.y = a.y + a.h), (a.h = -1 * a.h)),
                (this.ctxTemp.lineJoin = "round"),
                this.ctxTemp.beginPath(),
                console.log(a);
                  const head_len = 16;
                  const head_angle = Math.PI / 6;
                  var dx = (a.x + a.w) - a.x;
                  var dy = (a.y + a.h) - a.y;
                  const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);


                this.ctxTemp.beginPath();
                this.ctxTemp.moveTo(a.x, a.y), //fromx , fromy
                this.ctxTemp.lineTo(a.x + a.w, a.y + a.h), //tox,toy
                this.ctxTemp.stroke();

                this.ctxTemp.beginPath();
                this.ctxTemp.lineTo((a.x + a.w), (a.y + a.h));
                this.ctxTemp.lineTo((a.x + a.w) - head_len * Math.cos(angle - head_angle), (a.y + a.h) - head_len * Math.sin(angle - head_angle));

                this.ctxTemp.lineTo((a.x + a.w) - head_len * Math.cos(angle + head_angle), (a.y + a.h) - head_len * Math.sin(angle + head_angle));
                  this.ctxTemp.closePath(),
                  this.ctxTemp.stroke();
                  this.ctxTemp.fill();

                
        },
```

thanks